# How to create a relationship where all columns have many details

Tags: sql, relationship

I am working in a small personal project about capital expenses. There is one part I can't figure it out.

The tables i have are the following:
capex_form
capex_cashflow

When I create a capex_form I am able to request money and divide this money however I want in 13 months including this month (to show how I I will pay it in the next year). this will reflect in capex_cashflow who has 13 columns with either an amount or 0.

The problem comes here:

I need to be able to add many descriptions for each payment. For example:
in July 2019 I will spend 200 ( this is done), I need to enter a breakdown of this 200 dollars and a description. 50 dollars on one thing and 150 on another thing.

I added 3 columns per month which works, But then it will only let me add one description per month.

I was thinking I might be able to create another table for description, but how this is going to related to a specific column(month). As far as my brain gives, you relate one table with another table not column.

I also was thinking to create 13 tables for 13 months, but I think there should be something I am missing to avoid to create 13 unnecessary tables.

I appreciate any kind of help or guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward and a common thing.

Put an index column in the "header" table.  The header table is a summary of the information, so in your case may you create a table that just takes the capex_income.

CAPEX_FORM
Capex_id
Capex_Amount

Then create a payment table, the payment table can have a month column (only 1) and a capex_Id column, along with a description or whatever else you need

CAPEX_PAYMENT
Capex_payment_id
Capex_id
Payment_Amount
Month (1-13)
Description

Now because you have the Capex_id in this table, it will be related to the CAPEX table and you will be able to query all the payments that are associated like so

```
select payment_amount, month, description from capex_payment p join capex_form f on p.capex_id = f.capex_id
```

Comment: I was so blind this whole time. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction!